# Where can you use packages installed in python virtual env?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv

I'm a huge beginner so I'm not very informed about how packages really work. I know that you should create a virtualenv in your project folder to avoid version conflicts etc, and you're not supposed to put your actual project files in the virtual env. So if your project files are in your project directory on the same level as the virtualenv, can your project files "access" the things installed in the virtualenv? Can files outside of your directory access packages in your virtual env?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it all depends on the context. Your virtualenv can exist anywhere, be it in your project directory, or somewhere else.

When you want to use the virtualenv, you just have to call source command on it. Then whatever python command you execute on whichever file, will have access to the virtualenv. For example, if you store your virtualenv in `/home/user/project/virtualenv`, then you would do

```
source /home/user/project/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Then whatever you with the python, it would be the version installed in virtualenv. 
You can double check if you're using the global python or the virtualenv python by doing `which python`. It will either point to the global python path which is usually under `/usr/bin/python` or `/home/user/project/virtualenv/bin/python`.

So normally, you first do the `source command`, then you can do pip install on whatever packages you need already. It will be installed in the virtualenv and it will not conflict with other projects.